# Getting AssertionError in cypress custom command

Tags: javascript, cypress

My page object file is like below

```
/// <reference types='cypress' />

const LOGIN_PAGE_HEADER_TEXT = '.welcome-message > h1';

class LoginPage {
  get loginPageHeaderText() {
    return cy.get(LOGIN_PAGE_HEADER_TEXT, {timeout: 140000});
  }
}
export default LoginPage;
```

I want to use a custom command to check the Page header text and the text is dynamic

So I tried to write a custom command like below

```
Cypress.Commands.add('shouldContain', (element , text) => {
  cy.get(element).should('contain.text', text)
})
```

but when I am using the custom command in my test file I am getting error. I am trying to use the custom command like below

```
cy.shouldContain(loginPage.loginPageHeaderText, 'Welcome')
```

The Error I am getting :

Timed out retrying after 60000ms: expected { Object (0, length) } to contain text 'Forgot Password?', but the text was ''

If I use this

```
Cypress.Commands.add('shouldContain', (element , text) => {
  element.should('contain', 'text')
})
```

Then it shows the error

shouldcontain, text
AssertionError
object tested must be an array, a map, an object, a set, a string, or a weakset, but undefined given

Need Help

Answer (score 0):

You have to just write text instead of 'text'. And instead of contain, use `contain.text`, this will do a partial match of the inner text of the element.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('shouldContain', (element , text) => {
  element.should('contain.text', text)
})
```

Or, if you just want to use `contain` you can do this:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('shouldContain', (element , text) => {
  element.invoke('text').should('contain', text)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom commands can't take other commands as parameters.

The way to do this is to build a [Child Command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands#Child-Commands)

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('shouldContain', {prevSubject:true}, (element , text) => {

  cy.wrap(element).should('contain.text', text)     //  ✅ passes
})
```

You call it like this

```js
loginPage.loginPageHeaderText.shouldContain('Welcome')
```

---

Passing `loginPage.loginPageHeaderText` as a parameter doesn't work because it is evaluated too soon.

The result is still `undefined` because the commands haven't started running yet.